# What does "..." mean in a C function declaration?

Tags: c, function, variadic-functions

What does this mean?

```
void message(int x, int y, ...)
```

I can't understand what ... is.
Can anybody explain?

Comment: One related thing worth to note is that in C empty function parameters () means the same as (...), i.e. that the function may take any parameters. You need to use (void) to state that it doesn't take any. In C++ () means that it doesn't take any, as one would expect.

Comment: An empty parameter list `()` does **not** mean the same thing as `(...)`.  An empty parameter list means that the function takes a fixed, but unspecified, number of arugments.  `(...)` means that it takes a variable number of arguments (and is fairly useless, because the function will never be able to access those arguments without at least one fixed argument).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unspecified/variable number of parameters.  To handle such function you have to use the va_list type and va_start, va_arg, and va_end functions:

An example taken from [here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html):

```
  #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <stdarg.h>
        #include <stdio.h>

        int maxof(int, ...) ;
        void f(void);

        main(){
                f();
                exit(EXIT SUCCESS);
        }

        int maxof(int n args, ...){
                register int i;
                int max, a;
                va_list ap;

                va_start(ap, n args);
                max = va_arg(ap, int);
                for(i = 2; i <= n_args; i++) {
                        if((a = va_arg(ap, int)) > max)
                                max = a;
                }

                va_end(ap);
                return max;
        }

    void f(void) {
            int i = 5;
            int j[256];
            j[42] = 24;
            printf("%d\n",maxof(3, i, j[42], 0));
    }
```

You can find more details [here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html)

Answer (score 8):

`...` denotes a *variable* list of arguments that can be accessed through [va_arg, va_end and va_start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb57fad8.aspx).

Comment: some good programmer are here.
you are one of them.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You have defined a function message somewhere that takes at least two arguments of type int and then some optional arguments indicated by the "...". ([printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) is another function taking optional arguments).

The optional arguments can be accessed using the [va_*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb57fad8(VS.71).aspx) functions.

Answer (score 2):

... represents final argument passed as an array or as a sequence of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It's the variable argument formal parameter. From the syntactical prospective it allows you pass a variable number of parameters (at least two, which are x and y, but even more).